# Multiple Tomcat Containers using Docker

Tags: port-forwarding, docker

I need a machine to run 2 BPM engines for comparisom. I'm running Camunda BPM in port 8080 so I want bonita to answer in port 8081 on the same host.

I've installed the appliance with the following command:

```
docker run --name bonita -d -p 8081:8081 bonita
```

According to [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/bonita/) docs

Docker ps shows the images as running.

```
 [root@blah ~]# docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
    de6666d646a5        bonita                                "/opt/files/startup.s"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, 8080/tcp   bonita
    017fb48c67c4        camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest   "/usr/local/bin/confi"   4 days ago          Up 4 days           0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             camunda
```

Still the bonita instance does not answer as an application on port 8081.

Am I missing some configuration detail?

Comment: With the information you are giving, the only thing one can tell is that port 8081 on the host is connected to port 8081 on the container de6666d646a5. That doesn't mean anything in the container is listening. It also doesn't mean that you can access that port from another machine (if you do so) as there might be a firewall running. I would change the Dockerfile to include `telnet` and then rebuild & Up, to start bash in the container and `telnet localhost 8081` to see if bonita is running in the container as a start.

Comment: @Anthon you are right the port is not open. Answering, I will check about firewall configurations here.

 telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 8081
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
^C
me@blah:~$ telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 8080
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx
Escape character is '^]'.